# Passing an array and variable to a method and returning a smaller array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, methods

Had no luck the first time I had posted my question so I thought I would try again. I am a new Java programmer working on a little segment of code currently. In short I have created an array and a variable, what I would like this program to do is take the array and variable, pass it down to a method, have the method look at the array and if any of the numbers in the array are the same as the variable "8", take them out of the array "create a new array" return this array back to main and print it out.

**I would like the array {2,4,8,19,32,17,17,18,25,17,8,3,4,8} to display {2,4,19,32,17,17,18,25,17,3,4} after being passed back to main please explain to me what I am doing wrong keep in mind I am brand new to java.**

```
public class Harrison7b
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      int[] arrayA = {2,4,8,19,32,17,17,18,25,17,8,3,4,8};
      int varB = 8;
      // Call with the array and variable you need to find.
    int[] result =  newSmallerArray(arrayA, varB);

    for(int x = 0; x < arrayA.length; x++)
    {
      System.out.print(arrayA[x] + " ");


    }

   }

   public static int[] newSmallerArray( int[] arrayA, int varB)
   {
      int count = 0;   

      for(int x = 0; x < arrayA.length; x++)
      {
         if(arrayA[x] == varB)
         {
            count++;
         }
      }
         int [] arrayX = new int[arrayA.length - count];

         int index = 0;


      for(int B = 0; B < arrayA.length; B++)
      {
         if(arrayA[B] != varB)
         {
           index++;
         }
      }
      return arrayX;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed to initialize array arrayX, try following solution

```
 public class Harrison7b
  {
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
    int[] arrayA = {2,4,8,19,32,17,17,18,25,17,8,3,4,8};
    int varB = 8;
    // Call with the array and variable you need to find.
    int[] result =  newSmallerArray(arrayA, varB);

  for(int x = 0; x < result.length; x++)  {
    System.out.print(result[x] + " ");
   }

 }

  public static int[] newSmallerArray( int[] arrayA, int varB)
   {
  int count = 0;   

  for(int x = 0; x < arrayA.length; x++)
  {
     if(arrayA[x] == varB)
     {
        count++;
     }
  }
     int [] arrayX = new int[arrayA.length - count];

     int index = 0;


  for(int B = 0; B < arrayA.length; B++)
  {
     if(arrayA[B] != varB)
     {
         arrayX[index]= arrayA[B];
       index++;
     }
  }
  return arrayX;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple one liner should suffice:

```
    public static int[] newSmallerArray( int[] arrayA, int varB)
{
    return Arrays.stream(arrayA).filter(i -> i != varB).toArray();
}
```